# SQL query add count information

Tags: sql, count

I have a query which works fine:

```
SELECT
 b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect
FROM
 BUG b
JOIN LINK l ON b.BG_BUG_ID = l.LN_BUG_ID
JOIN TEST t ON l.LN_ENTITY_ID = t.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'Open') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS LIKE '%Re%') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS LIKE '%En%') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'Fixed') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'New') AND
 (l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TEST')
ORDER BY b.BG_BUG_ID ASC
```

The output is:

```
DEFECT
------
2222
3333
4444
```

Now I want to add a separate row with the total number of **t.TS_TEST_ID** for each **b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect** So it should look like:

```
DEFECT Number_of_test_ids
------ ------------------
2222    26
3333    14
4444    55
```

I do not know where to add the **SELECT COUNT (?)** in order to produce the result ?

Comment: `b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect, count(*)...` and then before the order by: add `GROUP BY b.BG_BUG_ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
 b.BG_BUG_ID as Defect, count(distinct t.TS_TEST_ID) as Number_of_test_IDs
FROM
 BUG b
JOIN LINK l ON b.BG_BUG_ID = l.LN_BUG_ID
JOIN TEST t ON l.LN_ENTITY_ID = t.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'Open') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS LIKE '%Re%') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS LIKE '%En%') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'Fixed') OR
 (b.BG_STATUS = 'New') AND
 (l.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TEST')
GROUP BY B.BG_BUG_ID
ORDER BY b.BG_BUG_ID ASC
```

you're using aggregate functions which require a group by clause.

you may need to remove the distinct if you want to count duplicate t.ts_test_Ids; or if you know duplicates will not exist, or if you actually want to count the same id twice.

Comment: In this case duplicates do not exist. I missed the Group By! Thanks to you my headache will be better :)